# parse server: include pointer in live query in javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, ionic2, parse-server

I am using parse server to live query a class containing rows with pointers.
When I use `include()` in the normal query it get all the data of the pointer but in the live query I only get the `objectId`

Code:

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current(); 
const Conversation = Parse.Object.extend("conversations");

var fromQuery = new Parse.Query(Conversation);
fromQuery.equalTo("from", currentUser );

var toQuery = new Parse.Query(Conversation);
toQuery.equalTo("to", currentUser);

var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(fromQuery, toQuery);
mainQuery.include("to")
mainQuery.include("from")
mainQuery.include("lastMessage")
// FIXME: DEBUG:
this.convsubscription = mainQuery.subscribe();

mainQuery.find().then((conversations) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < conversations.length; i++){
   var object = conversations[i]
  this.conversations.unshift(object);
  }
})


this.convsubscription.on('update', (object) => {
  // we will get the index of updated object     
  var index = this.conversations.findIndex(x => x.id == object.id);
  console.log(index);
  // then we will remove the old object and insert the updated one
  this.conversations.splice(index, 1 ,object)

  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.conversations[index].get('lastMessage')))
})
```

When I do `JSON.stringify(this.conversations[index].get('lastMessage'))` it only gives the `objectId`. I need a way to access the content of the pointer `lastMessage`

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`includeKey()`/`include()` isn't supported in Live Queries:

> this is a server side issue, the **includeKey is ignored when subscribing to the query**. The decision tree is processed synchronously after an object is saved on parse-server, therefore we don't have the opportunity to inject inclusions. We'd need to refactor the whole serverside logic in order to support those.

See related issues to keep track:

- https://github.com/parse-community/ParseLiveQuery-iOS-OSX/issues/30
- https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/1686

Comment: so is there is any method i can use to achieve the same results?

Comment: Yeah, you need to fetch the data before accessing it.